# I am unable to request data from two table on typegraphql type-orm

Tags: typescript, graphql, typeorm, typegraphql

I am making a graphQl API using TypeGraphQl with Postgress Database and TypeORM.

I am these two tables (shortened)

User

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {

  @Field()
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id!: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Article, (article: Article) => article.author)
  public articles: Article[];
```

And Articles written by user

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Article extends BaseEntity{
  @Field()
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  articleId!: string;


  @ManyToOne(() => User, (author: User) => author.articles)
  author: User;
```

**Problem**
I am unable to make a query that would typically return the related info, in other words, one query that returns both an article and the user who wrote the article.

**Resolvers**
Article

```
Resolver(() => Article);
export class ArticleResolver {
  @Query(() => [Article])
  public async getArticles() {
    const articles = await Article.find();
    return articles;
  }
```

User

```
Resolver(() => User);
export class RegisterResolver {
  @Query(() => [User])
  public async getUsers() {
    const users = await User.find();
    return users;
  }
```

This query gets the articles successfully

```
{

  getArticles{
    articleId
    title
    cells

  }
}
```

I want to make a query that also gets the author, and vice-versa for the Users I get the articles he had written.

From what I searched, this should be the query, but it is not recognized in the playground

```
{

  getArticles{
    articleId
    title
    cells
    author{
      lastName
    }
  }
}
```

I know that I should use `Field()` decorator to make those requests. But I am getting this error if I add it `Error: You need to provide explicit type for Article#author !` because of the ORM
Is there a way to configure `Field()` decorator to make it work? Or am writing the query wrongly?

Answer (score 2):

You need to write field resolvers that resolve the relation between article and author by using TypeORM repository.

You can see some examples in the repo:
https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/blob/master/examples/typeorm-basic-usage/resolvers/recipe-resolver.ts#L65-L76